# Change child layout make AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior incorrectly

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Here is my layout:

`CoordinatorLayout
    AppBarLayout
        ...
        AnimatableTabs
    SwipeRefreshLayout`

And there is no problem now.

Now The Behavior of Down Gesture is:

1.Expand AppBarLayout first.

2.show pullDownRefresh Circle of SwipeRefreshLayout second.

[image]

But,after I add a animate for AnimatableTabs.

```kotlin
appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
    ...

```
// FIXME: 2018/3/5
//This code make behavior incorrectly.
ll_tabs.apply {
    ll_tabs_left.apply widthProvider@ {
        layoutParams = (layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
            leftMargin = (this@widthProvider.width * collapsedHotPercent).toInt()
        }
    }
    ll_tabs_right.apply widthProvider@ {
        layoutParams = (layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
            rightMargin = (this@widthProvider.width * collapsedHotPercent).toInt()
        }
    }

    //It seems requestLayout() make behavior incorrectly.
}
```

}

There is a problem happened:

The Behavior of Down Gesture is:

Expand AppBarLayout and show pullDownRefresh Circle at the same time.

[image]

And here is code:

[code on GitHub](https://github.com/dyguests/K6Demo/blob/questionOnStackOverFlow/app/src/main/java/com/fanhl/k6demo/MainActivity.kt)

Anyway to fix it?It seems requestLayout() make behavior incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. by changed xml structure:

`CoordinatorLayout
    AppBarLayout
        ...
        Tabs
    AnimatableElements
    SwipeRefreshLayout`

And now I can use custom behavior.